# OpenTK: Passing unifrorm array and vec2d to fragment shader

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, opentk

I followed [this](https://opentk.net/learn/chapter1/1-creating-a-window.html) tutorial to completion, and created [this](https://github.com/Ibrahim9999/Riemann-Mating) project based on that code, which involves sending an array of vec2's to the [fragment shader](https://github.com/Ibrahim9999/Riemann-Mating/blob/master/OpenTK%20Reimann%20Mandlebrot/Shaders/shader.frag). However, I'm struggling to implement that efficiently, as all my attempts to pass an array into the shader have failed (only the first element would go through, the rest would be zero). Currently, I'm bypassing this issue by creating individual uniforms for each element, but this is not ideal at all (there are 4 arrays, each with 76 elements). Furthermore, I'd eventually like to replace those arrays with dvec2 (Vector2d in OpenTK), but I'm failing to even pass one and I'm not sure why... I've tried using every relevant overload of GL.Uniform2, but none seem to be working. Here's the relevant snippets of my code (the full code can be viewed from the above links):

```
    // These two functions successfully get the values to the shader
    public void SetVector2(string name, Vector2 data)
    {
        GL.UseProgram(Handle);
        GL.Uniform2(uniformLocations[name], data);
    }
    // But this one does so very undesirably, passing to independent variables rather than directly to a uniform array
    public void SetVector2Array(string name, Vector2[] data)
    {/*
        // This fails
        var floats = new float[data.Length * 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length * 2; i += 2)
        {
            floats[i] = data[i / 2].X;
            floats[i + 1] = data[i / 2].Y;
        }

        GL.UseProgram(Handle);
        //GL.Uniform2(uniformLocations[name], data.Length, floats);
        GL.Uniform2(uniformLocations[name + "[0]"], data.Length, floats);*/

        GL.UseProgram(Handle);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            GL.Uniform2(uniformLocations[name + i], data[i]);
        }
    }


    // This fails altogether... not really sure what value this sends, but it's not the right one
    public void SetVector2d(string name, Vector2d data)
    {
        double[] d = new double[]
        {
            data.X,
            data.Y,
        };

        GL.UseProgram(Handle);
        GL.Uniform2(uniformLocations[name], 2, d);
    }
```

My fragment shader looks like this (I'd like to replace each of the 4 arrays with a simple "uniform vec2 array_name"):

```
#define MAX_MATING_ITER 76

uniform vec2 ma0;
uniform vec2 ma1;
uniform vec2 ma2;
uniform vec2 ma3;
uniform vec2 ma4;
uniform vec2 ma5;
uniform vec2 ma6;
uniform vec2 ma7;
uniform vec2 ma8;
uniform vec2 ma9;
...
uniform vec2 md67;
uniform vec2 md68;
uniform vec2 md69;
uniform vec2 md70;
uniform vec2 md71;
uniform vec2 md72;
uniform vec2 md73;
uniform vec2 md74;
uniform vec2 md75;

// The 4 arrays I use
vec2 ma[MAX_MATING_ITER];
vec2 mb[MAX_MATING_ITER];
vec2 mc[MAX_MATING_ITER];
vec2 md[MAX_MATING_ITER];

void main()
{
    ma[0] = ma0;
    ma[1] = ma1;
    ma[2] = ma2;
    ma[3] = ma3;
    ma[4] = ma4;
    ma[5] = ma5;
    ma[6] = ma6;
    ma[7] = ma7;
    ma[8] = ma8;
    ma[9] = ma9;
    ...
    md[66] = md66;
    md[67] = md67;
    md[68] = md68;
    md[69] = md69;
    md[70] = md70;
    md[71] = md71;
    md[72] = md72;
    md[73] = md73;
    md[74] = md74;
    md[75] = md75;

    // Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: I cannot find `Uniform2(int, double[])` overloads in OpenTK. Where does it come from? Basically, the shaders do not support `double`s.

Comment: @donggas90 `Uniform2(int, int, double[])`, `Uniform2(int, int, double*)` and `Uniform2(int, int, ref double)` are valid.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I was mistaken. I thought about mobile GL *ES* because currently Vulkan is much more popular than GL in desktops.